# Why do I have to enclose a function in another function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

When I write a function in JSON, why do I have to enclose it inside an anonymous function?

**This works:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.myurl.com',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
});
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.myurl.com',
        data: data,
        success: alert(data)
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, because you're *executing* `alert()` and trying to assign the *result* to the `success` callback, so this won't work (the *result* of `alert()` is `undefined`).  However you *can* do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.myurl.com',
    data: data,
    success: customFunc //*not* customFunc() which would call it
});
```

In this case `customFunc` will receive the same parameters as `success` passes, so it's signature should be: `customFunc(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)`, though it can be a subset, for example `customFunc(data)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that. You just using the **wrong** `syntax`.

The `success` property needs a function **expression** not a function() call (which then returns a value into `success`);

So

```
success: myfunction
```

instead of

```
success: myfunction()
```